# Is SaveToZipFile the only method to save xlsx?

Tags: java, xlsx, docx4j

I am trying to save changed xlsx file to OutputStream. However the only method I found was using deprecated method SaveToZipFile:

```
public void contentReplace(OutputStream ac_os) {
    SpreadsheetMLPackage lc_xlsxPackage = something;
    try {
        SaveToZipFile saveToZipFile = new SaveToZipFile(lc_xlsxPackage);
        saveToZipFile.save(ac_os);
    }
}
```

Is there anything else I could use? Something like `Docx4j.save()` but for xlsx documents?

Comment: org.docx4j.openpackaging.io3.Save

Comment: Thank You, I can't believe I missed this one.